# @End typescript decorator to ensure a method always calls at the end of the method chain

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I implemented fluent interface pattern in order to run my tests.

```
class User {
    public name: string;
    public works: (() => Promise<void>)[];

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.works = [];
    }

    public attemptsTo(tasks) {
        this.works = this.works.append(tasks);
    }

    public expects(expectations) {
        this.works = this.works.append(expectations);
    }

    async run(): Promise<void> {
        // Runs all works then resolves
    }
}
```

And I use it like below:

```
const admin = new User("Admin");
     await user
    .attemptsTo([EnterCredentials,Login])
    .expects([LoginSuccessfully])
    .attemptsTo([NavigateToUsersPage])
    .expects([SeeUsersList,AddNewUser])
    .run();
```

I want to get a compilation error if I forget to put `run()` at the end of the chain. Is there anyway to ensure that a `run()` expression is always put at the end?
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613429/how-to-ensure-that-builder-pattern-is-completed), there is an @End annotation in java to achieve this purpose. How can I implement @End in typescript?
Or if there is not anyway, How can I reimplement my class without requiring a `run` method call?

Comment: I don't think an @End decorator is possible in Typescript. You could maybe change your class so that `.expects` runs the work directly so you can avoid the `run` method?

Comment: I Used to do that, but in some cases, I need to make some assertions in `.expects` then continue to do other works.